# How do I create an IEditorInput instance from an IFile instance?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently implementing a custom MultiPageEditorPart where I want to have multiple pages when editing file type .xxx (so that file with same base name and .yyy appears in another page).

I have obtained the IFile reference of the .yyy file corresponding to the .xxx file, and now wish to instanciate a new TextEditor instance but it requires an IEditorInput instance for initialization.

How do I create an instance of IEditorInput using my IFile instance? I also of course have access to the IProject and the usual Eclipse classes.

Comment: how 'bout new FileEditorInput(iFile)?

Comment: @kem, that's right, you should answer the question so it does not sit unanswered.

Comment: @Francis Upton - fair enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
new FileEditorInput(iFile)
```

Comment: Gives you a little more reputation that way :)

Comment: One line answers are the best!